# How can I use the logic in a Laravel policy class to protect a vue router route?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, permissions, vuex, single-page-application

My application consists of an API built with Laravel, and a front-end SPA using Vue.js and Vue Router.

I've written a policy class in Laravel that has some logic to determine if a user is able to create/read/update/delete a resource. The pages to perform these actions are Vue Router routes, and are defined in my routes.js file following the normal url scheme:

```
GET  /tasks (all tasks)
GET  /tasks/:task (show task)
GET  /tasks/create (create task)
GET  /tasks/:task/edit (edit task)
...
```

Take for example the edit task route: I'd like to use the Vue Router navigation guards to redirect the user if they do not have permission to edit the task. That logic is defined in my API policy class with something like this:

```
// App\Policies\TaskPolicy

public function update(User $user, Task $task)
{
    return $user->hasRole('foo') && ($task->owner === $user->id);
}
```

In my Vue Router routes file how can I utilize the `TaskPolicy` logic and check if the user is able to edit a task without duplicating it in Vue.js?

Comment: You can't since they are different languages. You either duplicate the PHP logic in JavaScript, or send a server request to an enpoint that runs the PHP code (which is probably not a good user experience since you'll need to re-check the code when the update is being done anyway). Situations like this is why Node.js is becoming so popular

Answer (score 0):

I recommend calling an initial endpoint when Vue.JS first starts/loads. This endpoint should include a list of permissions that user has. Those permissions should define what user can see on the FE.

Regarding permissions for things such as update, one of the permissions can be called `task.update` if it's present within the initial endpoint then Vue.JS will know that logged in user can update a task.

Also, if user does call an endpoint for whatever reason, your Laravel App, thanks to Policy you created, should respond with 403 code.

Example permissions management plugin: Spatie Permission or you can create your own one... it depends on difficulty of your software

---

**UPDATE**

If you are listing all tasks from list endpoint, event the ones that dont belong to logged in user, than you can always add an extra attribute to the `Task` model that will indicate if logged in user can update the task. This attribute can be called `editable` and will be a boolean. If editable is false then Vue.JS knows not to display edit button and so onwrads.